# Rock, Paper, Scissors in JavaScript 13

Tags: javascript

the computer continue to warn me "
Oops, try again. Your code returned 'rock win!' instead of 'undefined' when the inputs are scissors and paper" even if the code is working

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
var compare=function(choice1,choice2){
    choice1=userChoice;
    choice2=computerChoice;
    if (choice1===choice2){
        return"The result is a tie!";
    } else if(choice1==="rock"){
       if (choice2==="scissors"){
           return"rock win!";
       } else {
           return"paper win!!";
       }
    } else if (choice1==="scissors"){
        if(choice2==="rock"){
            return"rock wins!";
        } else {
            return"scissors wins";
        }
    } else {
        if(choice2==="rock"){
            return"paper wins";
        } else {
            return"scissors wins";
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: It should be `if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice >= 0.34 && computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}`

Comment: sorry i'm still a beginner so i don't know what is the difference.

Comment: Can you include the complete code?  I see the `return` statements but I don't see the function they belong to.

Comment: in the `compare` function, why are you overriding the values of parameter `choice1` and `choice2`?

Comment: @VickyGonsalves Sorry I don't see the problem either. The  `else` in the `else if` makes the test on  `computerChoice >= 0.34` unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the code works if you call the compare function correctly and actually pass it the userChoice and computerChoice as parameters:

```js
 var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
 var computerChoice = Math.random();
 if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
   computerChoice = "rock";
 } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
   computerChoice = "paper";
 } else {
   computerChoice = "scissors";
 }

 function compare(choice1, choice2) {
   if (choice1 === choice2) {
     return "The result is a tie!";
   } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
     if (choice2 === "scissors") {
       return "rock win!";
     } else {
       return "paper win!!";
     }
   } else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
     if (choice2 === "rock") {
       return "rock wins!";
     } else {
       return "scissors wins";
     }
   } else {
     if (choice2 === "rock") {
       return "paper wins";
     } else {
       return "scissors wins";
     }
   }
 };

 console.log(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
```